# Does a Canadian amateur radio operator’s certificate expire?

Tags: legal, license, canada

I obtained my Canadian Basic with Honours certificate in the late 90's and haven't done much with it since. Was looking to get back into the hobby.

Has my certificate expired? Do I need to take the test again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RAC](https://www.rac.ca/en/amateur-radio/regulatory/certification/):

```
The Amateur Radio Certificates are valid for your lifetime.
```

Answer (score 3):

As a friend has just gone through exactly this, I can confirm that yes, your certificate and callsign are still valid. As wkm noted above, the RAC states that “[The Amateur Radio Certificates are valid for your lifetime](https://www.rac.ca/en/amateur-radio/regulatory/certification/)”.

Wile this is great for returning operators, it does mean that the Canadian [Amateur Radio Operator Certificates](http://apc-cap.ic.gc.ca/pls/apc_anon/query_amat_cs%24.startup) database contains many SKs and inactive hams.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S. it expires after ten years if you don't renew it. Don't know about Canada. [note to potential down voters: at the time I wrote this answer neither the title nor the question explicitly mentioned Canada]

Comment: Basic with Honours really only is a Canadian designation, though.